# linq to strongly typed datatable with nested query using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I am trying to convert following sql `select * from tblPBRule where PBRuleId = 123 and StartDate < = '20140902' and finishdate is null and PBCodeid  in (select PBCodeid from tblpbrule where PBHourstypeid IN (3,4,5,6))` into linq query within application

```
 Dim query As IEnumerable(Of PBRuleData.PBRuleRow) = From s In Me.PBRule.PBRule.AsEnumerable() _
                                                                        Where s.PBRuleId = .PBRuleId And s.StartDate <= .PBDate _
                                                                        And ((s.IsFinishDateNull) OrElse (s.FinishDate > .PBDate)) Select s
```

can anyone help me to complete this query

Answer (score 1):

Have just gone through the same search and found Brad's Blog which works for me as in my function below.

http://www.gorgando.com/blog/technology/asp-net/not-in-subquery-with-asp-net-linq-in-vb

Hope this helps.  The only difference between the 2 queries of the second table is the "Where Not" for the not in condition.

```
Private Enum InOrNotInSelect
    None = 0
    InTable = 1
    NotInTable = 2
End Enum

Private Function getNotInData(firstTable As DataTable,
                              secondTable As DataTable,
                              inOrNotIn As InOrNotInSelect,
                              keyField As String) As DataTable

    ' TODO: make keyField a ParamArray 
    '       (don't know how to write dynamic LINQ code yet)

    Dim loTable As DataTable = Nothing

    ' first of all do a query on the first table 
    Dim firstQuery = From dt1 In firstTable.AsEnumerable()
                     Select dt1.Field(Of String)(keyField)

    If inOrNotIn = InOrNotInSelect.NotInTable Then
        ' next do a query on the second table returning the rows NOT IN the first table
        Dim inNotInQuery = From dt2 In secondTable.AsEnumerable()
                           Where Not firstQuery.Contains(dt2.Field(Of String)(keyField))
                           Select dt2

        ' convert the rows to a table
        loTable = inNotInQuery.CopyToDataTable()

    ElseIf inOrNotIn = InOrNotInSelect.InTable Then
        ' next do a query on the second table returning the rows IN the first table
        Dim inNotInQuery = From dt2 In secondTable.AsEnumerable()
                           Where firstQuery.Contains(dt2.Field(Of String)(keyField))
                           Select dt2

        ' convert the rows to a table
        loTable = inNotInQuery.CopyToDataTable()
    End If

    ' remove debug code in production build
    For Each dRow As DataRow In loTable.Rows
        Debug.Print(dRow(keyField) & " - " & dRow("FullName"))
    Next

    Return loTable
End Function
```